# GitHub API for downloading token

Tags: github

While working on GitHub and command line i.e. perl scripting, I came across a scenario of downloading files from private repository without passing token each time.

Hence, would like to know GitHub API for downloading token using command line i.e. shell or perl scripting so that downloading process can be automated without password/token for private repository.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to skip password typing when using https:// on GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343068/is-there-a-way-to-skip-password-typing-when-using-https-on-github)

Comment: Thanks, dear. Provided link might help me think ahead in this scenario. Just to rephrase my expectation:- I am expecting "known GitHub authorization endpoint" for "gettoken" which would help to download tokens automatically from github server whenever script executes.